# Add Extra Field To Serialized JSON Object

Tags: java

I have the following code that I have implemented and am looking to generate a JSON object from it.

```
@JsonTypeName("Dog")
public class Dog{

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Breed")
    private String breed;

}
```

That produces the following JSON, which is what I would expect.

```
{
  "Dog":{
      "Name":"Rover",
      "Breed":"Collie"
  }
}
```

However, I would like to add the additional json property "DogElement" to my Java object and achieve something like the below.

```
{
  "Dog":{
    "DogElement":{
      "Name":"Rover",
      "Breed":"Collie"
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone got any suggestions on how I can get this?

Comment: I'm curious as to why this would be necessary given that your `Dog` JSON is reasonably encapsulated...

Comment: I am submitting a request to a REST service that is unfortunately not very well written, but I have no power of changing.

Answer (score 0):

Every Pojo class is equivalent to a Json object. If you want to make a nested Json from Pojos, use nested classes from Java. I'll show my quick example of how I did it with GSON library.

Main.java:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        DogElement dogElement = new DogElement();

        dogElement.setBreed("breed of bread");
        dogElement.setName("Rex");

        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setDogElement(dogElement);

        Dogs dogs= new Dogs();
        dogs.setDog(dog);

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Dog.json");
        writer.write(gson.toJson(dogs));
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Dog.java:

```
public class Dog {
    DogElement dogElement = new DogElement();

    public DogElement getDogElement()
    {
        return dogElement;
    }

        public void setDogElement(DogElement dogElement)   
    {
        this.dogElement = dogElement;
    }
}
```

DogElement.java:

```
public class DogElement 
{
    private String name;

    private String breed;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

Dogs.java:

```
public class Dogs {

    private Dog dog = new Dog();

    public Dog getDog() {
        return dog;
    }

    public void setDog(Dog dog) {
        this.dog = dog;
    }
}
```

Dog.json (The result):

```
{
  "dog": {
    "dogElement": {
      "name": "Rex",
      "breed": "breed of bread"
    }
  }
}
```

I can not see a reason of this structure, but I guess this is a simple example of nested Json from Pojo.